# Code completion XML not working on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was working on an android project for homework, and suddenly, while I was designing a layout, I realized that the code completion wasn't working, and I don't know why.
Here I post some photos:

[XML not completing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZfPU.png)

However, when I try to code some Java, the completion is working.

[Java does complete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDQ5E.png)

I don't know how to revert that, I tried to Invalidate Cache, turning off power saving mode, and nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gradle version from the one you are using presently. Then close and open project again.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting studio and Sync Project with Gradle files